Why is my dog behaving this way?
My dog is fine with us when we are in the house. He doesn’t growl or bite us but when we go outside to go to the car or get the mail or whatever when we go back inside he growls aggressively and goes to bite us. I dont understand why he does this.

With this little information it's impossible to give you any meaningful answer. My best advice is to hire a professional dog trainer who visits you at home, analyzes the problem and gives you tips on how to change your behavior in order to change your dog's behavior.
